# SQL unknown number of foreign columns as header column?

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables, one for draft items and anotherone to store meta information about those items e.g "item" and "item_meta"

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `item_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `item_status` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `item_meta` (
  `meta_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `meta_item_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `meta_value` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In "item_meta" the field "meta_item_id" references "item.item_id" so i can store unlimited meta informaations about every item. Can i produce a sql result that have every stored meta information about an item and produces a table with the value of "meta_key" as header and the value of "meta_value" as its value?

For e.g i store an item with the name "page" and create meta information

```
item_id item_title item_status
------------------------------
1       page       1

meta_item_id meta_key  meta_value
--------------------------------
1            viewable  1
1            groupable 1
1            editable  0
...
```

**I dont know before how many meta informations an item will get** and i want a result like

```
item_id item_title item_status viewable groupable editable ... all other meta keys
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       page    1           1        1         0        ... all other meta values
```

Is this possible only with sql or do i need to archive this after querying by php?

Greets

Comment: You need to dynamically build a sql pivot sentence, because as you say the elements for each item are variable

Comment: I read about pivot tables and also that it would be my solution but i cant find examples where the names are not hardcoded.. can you shw me at least one example with dynamic header names where i dont have to know the column names?

Comment: @user4438328 . . . Google "<your database name> dynamic pivot" and you will probably find lots of examples.

Comment: Sorry Gordon, but thats not an answer for SO. I am gogeling since days so please delete this comment it is annoying

Answer (score 1):

[image]    Dynamic SQL Query:

```
    create table item
(
  item_id  int,
  item_title  varchar(100),
  item_status int,
    );

  insert into item values(1,'page',1);
  create table item_meta
(
  meta_item_id  int,
  meta_key  varchar(100),
  meta_value int,
    );

    insert into item_meta values(1,'viewable',1);
    insert into item_meta values(1,'groupable',1);
    insert into item_meta values(1,'editable',0);

declare @col varchar(1000)
declare @sql varchar(2000)

select @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','')+ (meta_key)
from (select distinct meta_key as meta_key from item_meta) K;
set @sql='select item_id,item_title,item_status,' +@col+ '
from
(select item_id,item_title,item_status,meta_value,meta_key from item item
inner join
item_meta meta
on item.item_id=meta.meta_item_id)piv
pivot(max(meta_value)for meta_key in (' +@col+' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY item_id'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: are this 2 queries? what does "--select @col;" in the 4th row mean? sql gave me an error saying this clause was analyzed in the select statement before

Comment: Added screenshot. It is working fine for me.without error.

Comment: is this platform dependent? i am learning with phpmyadmin (MySQL, InnoDB)

Comment: I tried different server versions now on sqlfiddle, theyre all giving errors http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad1b1e/2

Comment: it seems to work in Microsoft SQL Server, but in no other one so this is not a solution, sorry

Answer (score -1):

```
    I don't know about PHP. But it is possible in sql using cross tab query or by pivot:

    create table item
(
  item_id  int,
  item_title  varchar(100),
  item_status int,
    );

  insert into item values(1,'page',1);
  create table item_meta
(
  meta_item_id  int,
  meta_key  varchar(100),
  meta_value int,
    );

    insert into item_meta values(1,'viewable',1);
    insert into item_meta values(1,'groupable',1);
    insert into item_meta values(1,'editable',0);


select
distinct
item_id,
item_title,
item_status,
min(case when meta_key='viewable' then meta_value end) as viewable,
min(case when meta_key='groupable' then meta_value end) as groupable,
min(case when meta_key='editable' then meta_value end) as editable
from item item
inner join
item_meta meta
on item.item_id=meta.meta_item_id
group by
item_id,
item_title,
item_status
```

Comment: That query is gonna return more than 1 record, you must group by later if you want to return the expected output

Comment: I think it won't as I am rotating the table.

Comment: This is also wrong because meta information is hard coded, i need it dynamic, i dont know the names of meta_key.

Comment: Written Dynamic query .Kindly check it.

Comment: I dont know the terms "viewable", "editable" and so on... thats just examples so i cant hard code it. exactely thats my problem

Comment: I didn't hard code . See above code. I written two query.Take a look at new one

Comment: what if the field names are different? "case when meta_key='viewable'" is hard coded because its not variable, thats really clear